# What exactly is an FQDA and how does it relate to multiple dynamic domain addresses?

Tags: networking, server, dns, email

I've had a Linux box running here for years.  It is pointed to by first.second.net and first1.second.net as rented from no-ip, and there's a script to tell no-ip what the outside IP address is for my router.  My router is set to forward a few ports to this computer.  It was mostly setup for testing the development of PHP scripts. I needed to also add a git service on it for some outside collaboration.  I initially attempted to use GitLab-CE.  I found that to be difficult.  I ended up installing a lighter-weight solution called Gogs.  I obtained a 3rd name from no-ip,  and called it third.second.net  Gogs required I install a mail program.  I was unsuccessful in getting PostFix to install, but succeded with sendmail.

Everything seems to be working well, except there is a lot of activity being logged.  One particular item is that /var/log/mail.log is filling up with the same repition error message:

```
May 25 03:00:01 SERVER2 sm-msp-queue[2899]: My unqualified host name (SERVER2) unknown; sleeping for retry
May 25 03:01:01 SERVER2 sm-msp-queue[2899]: unable to qualify my own domain name (SERVER2) -- using short name
May 25 03:20:01 SERVER2 sm-msp-queue[2997]: My unqualified host name (SERVER2) unknown; sleeping for retry
May 25 03:21:01 SERVER2 sm-msp-queue[2997]: unable to qualify my own domain name (SERVER2) -- using short name
May 25 03:40:01 SERVER2 sm-msp-queue[3092]: My unqualified host name (SERVER2) unknown; sleeping for retry
May 25 03:41:01 SERVER2 sm-msp-queue[3092]: unable to qualify my own domain name (SERVER2) -- using short name
```

So I am wondering, do I need to change my SERVER2 designation someone to some FQDN?  And what would I use for that FQDN, since I have 3 pointing to the system, and none of them have 'SERVER2' as a part of the name?  I think that having 2 errors every 20 minutes in the log is kinda excessive.

My Linux distribution is Kubuntu 18.04.04 LTS desktop.

Comment: To start with, which Linux distro have you installed (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Mint, et al.), & which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] & add that to your question, so all facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our one-way channel to you. All facts about your PC should go in the Question with [edit] as this is a Q&A site, not a general forum, so things work differently here.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_address